# Class 'mPDF' not found in Yii2

Tags: server, yii2, debian, mpdf

I have problem with my page on server.
I'm using yii2 framework and mPDF;
All configured according to the instructions: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/create-pdf-files-using-mpdf-in-yiiframework-2-0/

Page work on localhost on Windows and Xampp
When I try run page on Debian 8 I have error:

```
Class 'mPDF' not found
```

Configuration: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/create-pdf-files-using-mpdf-in-yiiframework-2-0/

function in php:

```
public function actionCreatepdf()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $generate_table = $request->post();

        $mpdf = new mPDF;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('view_pdf', ['data'=>$data]));
        $mpdf->Output('data.pdf', 'D');
        exit;
    }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it's not running on Debian

Comment: The probles was in composer file: autoloadnamespaces.php: corectly line in this file: 'mpdf' => array($vendorDir . '/mpdf/mpdf'),

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when migrating from Ubuntu (php 5.6) to CentOS 7 (PHP 7.1)

The easiest thing to do, without manually editing the composer file was to change the use/import in the controller:

```
//use mPDF;  #Php 5.6
use Mpdf\Mpdf; #Php 7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! As mentioned before it was due to capital cases.

I used following and it is now working on CENTOS 7 (probably similar on most Linux versions)

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
    use Yii;
    //use mPDF;  Note this line is Commented out
    use mpdf;
```

---

And then use it as follows:

```
public function actionIndex(){

            $model = new Mpdf();
            $model->SetHeader('header');
            $model->WriteHTML("PDF contents");
            $model->SetFooter('footer');
            $model->Output('MyPDF.pdf', 'D');
            exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case which i just resolved, adding 
**'mPDF\' => array($vendorDir . '/mpdf')** to autoload_psr4.php required me to namespace most of the class files in ../mpdf/classes using the line
**namespace mPDF;**
Also among the errors i fixed was changing include to include_once to prevent php from seeing some classes as duplicate declaration despite the presence of class_exists() test